# Cannot remove jpa child entity by persistance remove

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7, persistent

I can remove any row by plain HQL like

```
Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Cities WHERE id = :id");
```

But I want to remove It like

```
Cities city = em.getReference(Cities.class, 8);

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(city);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
```

And I got no warnings or errors

Models are simple

Countries (only OneToMany annotation)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Cities> cities;
```

Cities (only fk field)

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
private Countries country;
```

Things which I were trying are:

```
1) trying to apply orphanRemoval = true
2) cascade = CascadeType.MERGE to Cities
3) em.refresh(city)
```

Comment: You are saying "And I got no warnings or errors" thus with no errors the system worked. So what is the question?

Comment: I reach result after these changes:

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            city.setCountries(null);
            em.refresh(city);
            em.remove(city);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

Comment: The question is why there are no deletion without deletion FK in the child entity and refresh it like above :(

Answer (score 1):

You are removing a City, but what are you doing with the country's reference to that now removed city? If this is in the persistence unit, the cascade persist/merge option will cause it to be picked up and re-inserted, undoing your desired remove operation. You have to null out any references to the city before you can remove it. Your JPQL might work because you aren't loading anything into memory, so the Country (and its reference to the City) isn't there and so not checked when you commit. While it works, It isn't good to rely on